# Steam don't open after installing and updating

Tags: games, steam

Let me ask a very simple Question.
Why I can't open `steam` after install and update it?

I am a new `Ubuntu` user. I am currently using 16.10. I want to install steam in my laptop. So, download from [steam](http://store.steampowered.com/about/) and install it with `gdebi`. But without giving any error it opened up and update just fine. But after updating `steam client` it won't start again. It Just show the steam icon in the luncher for a few Seconds. Then vanish.
I tried to start with terminal

```
$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
/bin/bash: /home/jis/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1476379980)
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

**Notes:**
I tried some of the solutions

```
$rm ~/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6

$rm ~/.steam/steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

and

```
$LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6 /usr/$LIB/libgcc_s.so.1 /usr/$LIB/libxcb.so.1 /usr/$LIB/libgpg-error.so' /usr/bin/steam
```

But nothing worked for me.

SO can anyone help me, please.

Comment: Try `steam --reset` or `STEAM_RUNTIME=0 steam` from a terminal and check the output. Your other option is to uninstall steam and install from the repository `sudo apt install steam`

Comment: Steam downloads from the Steam website are only supported by LTS releases. Otherwise, install the 32-bit version of steam via the Multiverse repository, like @GrannySez stated.

Comment: $ `steam --reset`
same as privious error

Comment: Thanks for your help . problem is solved by `$sudo apt install steam` @GrannySez

Answer (score 0):

I updated my system to 16.10, then had to update Steam as stated in [this message](https://askubuntu.com/questions/842174/how-do-i-run-steam-in-ubuntu-16-10), which lists a forum thread provided by @Patrick Negus that unfortunately seems to no longer work.  It worked perfectly when it still existed.  I will see if I can remember the process.

Copy directories "SteamApps" and "userdata" from i believe `/usr/.steam/steam` and save them to the desktop if you already have games installed.

In terminal type: `sudo apt-get remove --purge steam-launcher` to remove steam

Remove the /usr/.steam directory, and the steam directory in your Home

Then remove the repository: `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:steam`

Update the repositories: `sudo apt-get update`

now reinstall steam: `sudo apt-get install steam`

Move the saved directories to Home/.steam/Steam

Edit the Steam script in /usr/games/ to add two lines before the last line starting with test:

find $runtime -name libgcc_s.so* -delete
find $runtime -name libxcb.so* -delete

I am sure I got a couple of things wrong, please double-check as I am still new and going from memory.

Comment: Tannk you for your answer.
My Problem Is already solved by this process
1) completely remove steam
        `$ sudo apt-get remove steam`
        `$ sudo apt-get purge stem`
        `$ sudo apt-get autoremove steam-launcher`
        `$ rm -rf /home/user_name/.steam`
        `$ rm -rf ~/.local/share/Steam`
2) Now Install `steam` with this commend
         `$ sudo apt install steam`
         `$ steam`

Comment: Great!  Glad to hear you got it working.